# How to remove object from an array if key value already exists - typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

i have this functions that adds more objects to an array, but the problem that i am facing is that if I have a key value exists in the array it still adds that key value, but I don't want to add it if exists already. This is what I have so far

```
 onCheckRecipe(e) {
    if (e.detail.checked === true) {
      let tickedRecipe = e.detail.value;
      let foundRecipeIngredients = [];
      let foundRecipe;
      this.loadedRecipes.filter(function (el) {
        if (el._id === tickedRecipe) {
          el.ingredients.map((elm) => {
            foundRecipe = elm;
            foundRecipeIngredients.push(foundRecipe);
          });
        }
      });
      this.groceryListUpdated = foundRecipeIngredients;
      this.groceryListDefault = this.groceryListDefault.concat(
        this.groceryListUpdated
      );
    }
  }
```

and in the console i receive smth like this:

```
(12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {name: "", quantity: ""}
1: {_id: "5f64ac1eb227fea1f63a5ca3", name: "avocado", quantity: "50g"}
2: {_id: "5f64ac1eb227fea1f63a5ca4", name: "lemon juice", quantity: "5g"}
3: {_id: "5f64ac1eb227fea1f63a5ca5", name: "small mozzarella pearls", quantity: "70g"}
4: {_id: "5f64ac1eb227fea1f63a5c9e", name: "almond flour", quantity: "10g"}
5: {_id: "5f64ac1eb227fea1f63a5c9f", name: "egg", quantity: "10g"}
6: {_id: "5f64ac1eb227fea1f63a5ca0", name: "unsalted butter", quantity: "30g"}
7: {_id: "5f64ac1eb227fea1f63a5ca1", name: "peanut butter", quantity: "50g"}
8: {_id: "5f64ac1eb227fea1f63a5c99", name: "chia seeds", quantity: "10g"}
9: {_id: "5f64ac1eb227fea1f63a5c9a", name: "cherries", quantity: "15g"}
10: {_id: "5f64ac1eb227fea1f63a5c9b", name: "honey", quantity: "30g"}
11: {_id: "5f64ac1eb227fea1f63a5c9c", name: "almond flour", quantity: "10g"}
length: 12
__proto__: Array(0)
```

what I want to do is to not add eg: almond flour twice if it exists already, but just the quantity. I've tried a lot of methods, but nothing seems to work. If you guys have any idea I. would really appreciate it.

Comment: If `e.detail.value` is the id, it will not work b/c both "almond flour" have different ids

Comment: Consider editing the code above to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play), where the only issue present is the one you're asking about.

Comment: @Emilien yes, you are right. I've checked it by name the instead, but still doesn't solve my issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was looking for it's something likes this

```
onCheckRecipe(e) {
    if (e.detail.checked === true) {
      for (let recipe of this.loadedRecipes) {
        if (recipe.name === e.detail.value) {
          recipe.ingredients.forEach((eachIngredient) => {
            let matchedIng = this.groceryList.find(function (foundIng) {
              return foundIng.name === eachIngredient.name;
            });
            if (matchedIng) {
              matchedIng.quantity =
                matchedIng.quantity + eachIngredient.quantity;
            } else {
              this.groceryList.push(eachIngredient);
            }
          });
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

First check if the item is present (by `findIndex`), if so, run a `map` and only increment the correct index.

If it's not present, well, just `concat` the new item.

Included below an example code. You will have to adapt to your needs, of course, but the idea is there.

```js
const items = [{
  _id: "1",
  name: "avocado",
  quantity: 50
}, {
  _id: "2",
  name: "pasta",
  quantity: 60
}]

function addItems(newItem) {
  const index = items.findIndex((curItem) => curItem.name === newItem.name);
  if (index >= 0) {
    return items.map((curItem, curIndex) => {
      return index === curIndex ? {
          ...curItem,
          quantity: curItem.quantity + newItem.quantity
        } :
        curItem;
    });
  } else {
    return items.concat(newItem);
  }
}

console.log('Current items', items);

console.log('Adding a known item', addItems({
  _id: "1232",
  name: "avocado",
  quantity: 50
}));

console.log('Adding a new item', addItems({
  _id: "23232332",
  name: "meat",
  quantity: 50
}));
```

Comment: According to alex's info, the same ingredient can have a different `_id`, this is the case with almond flour `5f64ac1eb227fea1f63a5c9e` - `5f64ac1eb227fea1f63a5c9c`.

If it's not a copy paste error on Alex's part, your function should filter by `name` and `not _id`.

Comment: And you don't need to map over the item list as you know the index you can directly access to it `items[index].quantity += newItem.quantity` and update the quantity attribute. I submit to you a update of your code :)

Comment: Hi! Yes, it was my mistake the filtering is by name and not _id indeed. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I have updated for the name filtering. And I usually don't suggest mutation on entry arguments, that's why I suggest for the `map`

Comment: Hi @alex, are you still needing help with your question? Otherwise, please accept the answer of it solves the issue